# Any idea or hint on how to solve the integral $ \int_{-1}^{1} (1-vx)^{-\gamma}(1-x^2) ^{d }\mathrm dx,$ where $\gamma>0$, $0\leq v<1$ and $d\geq-0.5$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Any idea or hint on how to solve the integral
$$ \int_{-1}^{1} (1-vx)^{-\gamma}(1-x^2) ^{d }\mathrm dx,$$
where $\gamma>0$, $0\leq v<1$ and $d\geq-0.5$?

Comment: The result seems to involve regularized hypergeometric functions, but can be obtained on the slightly larger parameter domain $v \in \Bbb{C} \smallsetminus \left( (-\infty,-1) \cup (1,\infty)\right)$, $\Re(d) > -1$, and $\gamma \in \Bbb{C}$.  Is it reasonable for your integral to require hypergeometric functions?

Comment: Yes, I would even say that a solution using hypergeometric functions was expected, but I could not find one with proper integral representation.